Android - how to make an autofill service app (confusing documentation by Google)
This is the official Google documentation on creating an autofill service.
I am trying to implement a simple service which gives user the option to fill in data from a database created by my application. To start off with, I am trying to display a single value in the autofill list hardcoded in the code - just to learn before starting to develop the actual app.
Let's look at the code block I am using, straight from the documentation:
override fun onFillRequest(
    request: FillRequest,
    cancellationSignal: CancellationSignal,
    callback: FillCallback
) {
    // Get the structure from the request
    val context: List<FillContext> = request.fillContexts
    val structure: AssistStructure = context[context.size - 1].structure

    // Traverse the structure looking for nodes to fill out
    val parsedStructure: ParsedStructure = parseStructure(structure)

    // Fetch user data that matches the fields
    val (username: String, password: String) = fetchUserData(parsedStructure)

    // Build the presentation of the datasets
    val usernamePresentation = RemoteViews(packageName, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1)
    usernamePresentation.setTextViewText(android.R.id.text1, "my_username")
    val passwordPresentation = RemoteViews(packageName, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1)
    passwordPresentation.setTextViewText(android.R.id.text1, "Password for my_username")

    // Add a dataset to the response
    val fillResponse: FillResponse = FillResponse.Builder()
            .addDataset(Dataset.Builder()
                    .setValue(
                            parsedStructure.usernameId,
                            AutofillValue.forText(username),
                            usernamePresentation
                    )
                    .setValue(
                            parsedStructure.passwordId,
                            AutofillValue.forText(password),
                            passwordPresentation
                    )
                    .build())
            .build()

    // If there are no errors, call onSuccess() and pass the response
    callback.onSuccess(fillResponse)
}

data class ParsedStructure(var usernameId: AutofillId, var passwordId: AutofillId)

data class UserData(var username: String, var password: String)

Problem 1: the setValue method is deprecated.
Problem 2: It is a bit unclear to me as to where the AutofillId for the setValue method is coming from. The only I am able to get the AutofillId and AutofillValue fields is by doing this:
val value = structure.getWindowNodeAt(0).rootViewNode.autofillValue
val id = structure.getWindowNodeAt(0).rootViewNode.autofillId

Final problem: I was able to write some code which can compile and run but upon trying to get the item to show, I get nothing. I can see the onFillRequest method being called but I think I am going wrong somewhere because there are no errors and I'm not getting anything. This is the final code I've written:
class FrequentPhrasesService : AutofillService() {

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
    override fun onFillRequest(
        request: FillRequest,
        cancellationSignal: CancellationSignal,
        callback: FillCallback
    ) {
        val context: List<FillContext> = request.fillContexts
        val structure: AssistStructure = context[context.size - 1].structure
        val value = structure.getWindowNodeAt(0).rootViewNode.autofillValue
        val id = structure.getWindowNodeAt(0).rootViewNode.autofillId

        val usernamePresentation = RemoteViews(packageName, R.layout.simple_list_item_1)
        usernamePresentation.setTextViewText(R.id.text1, "hello world")

        val dataset = Dataset.Builder()
        val fieldBuilder = Field.Builder()

        if (value != null) {
            fieldBuilder.setValue(value)
        }

        val presentationsBuilder = Presentations.Builder()
        presentationsBuilder.setMenuPresentation(usernamePresentation)
        fieldBuilder.setPresentations(presentationsBuilder.build())
        
        if (id != null) {
            dataset.setField(id, fieldBuilder.build())
        }

        callback.onSuccess(FillResponse.Builder().addDataset(dataset.build()).build())
    }

    override fun onSaveRequest(request: SaveRequest, callback: SaveCallback) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
}

Normally when I'm learning something I can find tons of documentation and resources online, but barely anything for this. And yes, I've gone into the settings and set my app as the autofill service. I'm using API 34 (both physical and AVD) for testing.

There are quite a few AutofillService implementations in Kotlin on GitHub. You might consider examining some of those, if you have not done so already. FWIW, I have a chapter on autofill in this older book of mine, which might help with concepts, though its use of the API probably is out of date.

@CommonsWare I did see your comment on one of the other posts on SO. I did go through the book and the link you provided of GitHub but I'm not able to make out how to go about it. If you can and have the time, some sample code of a simple entry would help immensely. Even if I could get one entry to show up, I would take it from there. Thanks!

Personally, I have not worked with autofill in years -- I did enough to write that chapter and file some security bug reports, and that's it.

So I found the exact-ish code used in the documentation and I'm still getting nothing :(
